# Angular 8 : What is the best way to store some temp data to transfer between the components

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I need to store some temporary data to communicate between the component. (say the data is JSON). We have a lot of ways like LocalStorage, SessionStorage, Service, CustomEvent etc... What is the best way in this scenario?

Comment: If you don't need data to be persistent (after leaving / returning to site, for example) but just to be accessible at any point during a given session, I'd say that the fastest and easiest is BehaviourSubject.

Answer (score 0):

If Components are in **Parent-Child** relationship then you can go with [Input-Ouput decorators](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs), If they are **sibling** then go with services.
In some scenario developer uses queryParams (but make sure to encrypt the data).